# On Button Click, Maintain or Change Value in the Same Activity

Tags: android

In the code  code I pass the new value to same Activity (OneActivity), but when I click the button it seems to open a new Activity (refresh screen). How to modify thr code below to maintain the Activity and not refresh it when clicked the button?

```
final Button fruit_q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fruit_q);
fruit_q.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //Next step
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OneActivity.class);

                if(position != 35) //35 is end of index in gridview array
                {
                    // passing array index
                    String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position+1]);
                    i.putExtra("image_name", name);
                    i.putExtra("id", position+1);
                    i.putExtra("rememberID_frist", firstTimeID_1);
                    i.putExtra("rememberID_second", position+1);
                    whatfruit.stop();
                    correctAnswer.stop();
                }
                else // ber sin chea answer dol index 35 hery jang back to index 0
                {
                    // passing array index
                    //String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position+1]);
                    i.putExtra("image_name", "apple");
                    i.putExtra("id", 0);
                    i.putExtra("rememberID_frist", firstTimeID_1);
                    i.putExtra("rememberID_second", 0);
                    whatfruit.stop();
                }
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: you probably need shared preferences

Comment: if you create an Intent and call startActivity(i), obviously the Activity gets refreshed. You might want to have global variables which you will change in onClick().

Comment: Dear Valentino, could you please modify on my code, because I tried for 2hours already but still can't find out the solotion.

Comment: What exactly do you do with the values in your Activity?

Comment: @user1731690 i got confused. change value of what?

Comment: Use a simple object and a function to pass values across! That is much easier and clear!

Comment: Raghunandan, not change the value, I just don't want to refresh activity because the value passing to the same name activity. Just like MainActivity and onClick go to MainActivity, but when onClick button the MainActivity is reload, what I need is MainActivity don't load just change the new value that's it.

Comment: Try using function and pass value to that function button's click event OR make a global variables and assign them new value onclick of button.

Comment: Dear Velentino, I am passing the new value of question & answer buy ID picture. Example: if picture is apple.png in index 1 then the answer is Apple (Text), then Next Button will show on the screen (i set ID as R.id.fruit_q) then when onClick on Next question Button(R.id.fruit_q) it will go to the next question picture but in same name activity.

Comment: check out my answer and have a look if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just want to increment the value of position when clicked on the button and the position is not 35. Since you pass four values as IntentExtras, try the following:

Create the four values you pass as Extras also as global variables in your Activity.
In `onCreate()`, you could assign your passed values to this variables (e.g. position). Then all you have do to in the `onClickListener` is

```
fruit_q.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //Next step
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(position != 35) //35 is end of index in gridview array
                {
                    id = position + 1;
                    secondID = position + 1;
                }
                else // ber sin chea answer dol index 35 hery jang back to index 0
                {
                    id = 0;
                    secondID = 0;
                }
                // call method to show this new values (1)
            }
        });
```

The method mentioned in (1) you can design so that it sets up all visual and background calculating things of your Activity in order that it can be called both from `onCreate()` and from your `onClickListener`.

**Example**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    // ...    

    private int a, b, c;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
        // do usual stuff
        a = getIntent().getIntExtra("a");
        b = getIntent().getIntExtra("b");
        c = getIntent().getIntExtra("c");
        // ...
        fruit_q.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                a += 1;
                b += 2;
                c -= 3;
                displayStuff();
            }
        }
        displayStuff();
    }

    private void displayStuff(){
        // get displaying components like TextView
        // set some of the values like a, b or c as Text
    }

    // ...
}
```

I do not checked this code directly, it should just show you the principle I mean. Like this, you can manipulate existing values directly in the Activity without refreshing it.